# Why Media query is not working on chrome browser?

Tags: css, media-queries

Media query is not working on chrome browser. This is my css its not working on chrome browser.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:1000px) {
    .catalog-product-view section#body .product_page .detail_contentmain .detail_content {
       width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, your path to `.detail_content` most probably isn't correct. Check on inspect element first if that works, if it does, copy straight from there and paste to your code.

Comment: this code us working on firefox browser

Comment: just not working for chrome browser

Comment: It was a cache issue in magento now its working after clear complete cache. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code first

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:1000px) {
body{
   display: none !important;
}}
```

Because it's a problem with your selector, not media query.

Comment: This code is working on firefox but not working on chrome for me i have tried it

Comment: Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)   This is my chrome version

Comment: Then it's another issue not media query issue.
Have you put meta tag(<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">) in your header?

Comment: It was a cache issue in magento now its working after clear complete cache. :)